# How to change the default UDK game folder?

Tags: udk

How can I change the default UDK game folder, the folder where it takes config files from?
Looking at the engine configuration files, it is taking it from `%GAME%Game/`, and when that's `UDK`, it loads from `UDKGame`, but how do I change the `%GAME%`?

Answer (score 1):

Without license you cannnot.
I have tried a few months ago but got an error at compile and cooking time.

Others with the same issue:

http://forums.epicgames.com/threads/841042-How-to-set-up-a-game-project-in-the-root-UDK-directory-outside-of-UDKGame